Rear disc brakes work intermittently
My son's 26" mountain bike's rear mechanical disc brakes work when it's on my bike stand, but will not grip or stop when the bike is on the ground.
When there is any downward force on the rear wheel, the brake doesn't work. When there is no force, it works. I'm new to disc brakes - what would be the first thing to check? Thanks!




Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Some pictures might help here; it's possible that the brakes aren't gripping with much force even on the stand, but are enough to halt the very light unweighted wheel.  On the stand, with the brake applied, how hard is it to manually force the wheel to rotate?

It is impossible to rotate the wheel when the bike is on the stand and the brake is applied - the brake grips it very well. I couldn't paste pictures since they were too large so I put them on a Google doc (if there's a better way, please let me know) - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1idMbENr8lMsxk4QSSbWqYI0L3XviNw30BdmFtrAUOAE/edit?usp=drivesdk

You can apply far less force with your hand, on a stand, than with your foot, on the ground. Even being able to resist foot pressure from a standing start isn't enough for decent stopping. So you need to check everything. If I try to load your Google doc I get one picture, that shows the rotor and a quick release, but nothing of the caliper.

OK, on desktop the google doc works better and I can see all the photos.  They're not BB5 clones (wrong pads) but a shot of the inside of the caliper through the spokes would confirm a couple of points in my answer

I've added the pictures inline, from the google doc with whatever auto-resizing happened by chance

You said the problem happens when the bike is on the ground. Do you mean "as soon as the tyres touch the ground" or "as soon as someone gets on the bike?" Is something pinching the cable housing so that it only happens when the bike is under load?

This is a bit of a collection of guesses, but here's what I'd try with mechanical discs lacking stopping power.

first, check the lever doesn't bottom out before the brakes do. You may need to tighten a barrel adjuster or adjust a pinch bolt if so.

then check the fixed pad. Most, but not all, mechanical disc brakes only move one pad, and use that to press the rotor into the other pad. The gap between the fixed pad and the rotor needs to be very small for good contact (well under 1mm). A slight pinging sound from a lightly warped rotor is better than a big gap. You'll probably have to work through the wheel to tighten a screw or cap.

you should be able to see through the caliper at this point, and have minimal gaps both sides of the rotor, plus minimal sideways movement of the rotor when you squeeze the lever.

even if you can get the pads running close, very worn or glazed pads might need replacing. You need to find out the brake model and get the right pads as there are many designs.

if there's plenty of material on the pads it's worth cleaning the rotors. There are proprietary brake cleaners, or use denatured alcohol (meths, but not surgical spirit or rubbing alcohol as some compositions can leave oils behind). Solvents aren't usually effective on pads.

(resin) pads that have got really hot, e.g. by dragging them on long descents, can have their surfaces damaged. They go much shinier than they should be. If there's plenty of material left, you can sand them back to good stuff. I would put fairly fine good quality sandpaper (better still, silicon carbide wet or dry paper) on a flat surface, and move the pad against it.



One problem with disk brakes is that the wheel has a lot more leverage on the brake due to mechanical advantage.
Meaning, that the wheel is 4-10x larger than the rotor allowing the momentum of riding to overpower a weak brake.  Your hand testing in the stand may not be generating the same forces.
Brake pads are wear items like chains.  It could be your pads are just worn and not generating as much "squeeze"  Pads also absorb oil and other contaminants reducing power.
Most calipers have an adjustment for pad wear, often a relatively thick screw.  Some cable-operated calipers are single-sided adjust and the other side is taken up by the lever, so a barrel adjuster on that side.    Fancier cable brakes may be dual-sided.
Start by pulling out the pads and inspecting them.  If in doubt, replacement  is straightforward and relatively inexpensive.  Also clean down your rotor with IPA and clean rags.

That's isopropyl alcohol, not India pale ale, for anyone confused!

@ChrisH Though the other kind of IPA may also be useful if you're having issues getting your brakes working properly.
